# reading and writing simultaneously from the same socket in windows

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, send, recv

I'm writing a server in C++ on windows. On connection, the server creates two threads to handle the request - one constantly reading the input from the socket and the second constantly writes output to it. I'm experiencing problems with it because when there's no input from the client but output to send to it thread #1 is blocking on recv() making thread two block on send() and not write it's data.

Is there a way to send() to a socket although it is already in blocking recv()?

Thanks

EDIT:

I took out the relevant code and reproduced the issue. if I comment out the AfxThreadCall to the readThread, the data is being sent. otherwise it isn't. the client is a simple client that prints what it recieves.

```
SOCKET m_sockIOSrv = NULL;
SOCKET m_sockIO = NULL;

UINT readThread(LPVOID args)
{
    WSABUF DataBuf;
    DWORD RecvBytes;
    DWORD Flags = 0 ;
    char buf[4096];
    DataBuf.len = 4096;
    DataBuf.buf = buf;
    while (true)
    {
        int ret = WSARecv(m_sockIO, &DataBuf, 1, &RecvBytes, &Flags, NULL,     NULL); // Read some data...
        if (ret == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            printf("ERROR: WSARecv: %d", WSAGetLastError());
            return 1;
        }
        printf("jobleader - got %d from recv\n", RecvBytes);
    }
    return 0;
}

UINT writeThread(LPVOID args)
{
    WSABUF DataBuf;
    DWORD SendBytes;
    DWORD Flags;

    char buf[] = { 'a', 'a', 'a' };
    DataBuf.len = 3;
    DataBuf.buf = buf;
    while (true)
    {
        DWORD dwWritten;
        WSASend(m_sockIO, &DataBuf, 1, &dwWritten, 0, NULL, NULL);
    }
    return 0;
}

SOCKET ServerSocket(unsigned int & port) {
    // Our server socket
    SOCKET s = WSASocket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP, NULL, 0, 0);
    if (s == INVALID_SOCKET)
        return s;

    SOCKADDR sa;
    sa.sa_family = AF_INET;
    memset(sa.sa_data, 0, sizeof(sa.sa_data));
    if (bind(s, &sa, sizeof(sa))) {
        closesocket(s);
        return INVALID_SOCKET;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in sa_in;
    int sz = sizeof(sa_in);
    if (getsockname(s, (struct sockaddr *)&sa_in, &sz)) {
        closesocket(s);
        return INVALID_SOCKET;
    }

    if (listen(s, 50)) {
        closesocket(s);
        return INVALID_SOCKET;
    }

    port = ntohs(sa_in.sin_port);
    return s;
}
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    unsigned int ioPort = 0;
    WORD wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
    WSADATA wsaData;
    if (WSAStartup(wVersionRequested, &wsaData))
    {
        if (!AfxSocketInit())
        {
            printf("ERROR: Unable to initialize WinSock DLL");
            exit(2);
        }
    }
    m_sockIOSrv = ServerSocket(ioPort);
    if (m_sockIOSrv == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        int lastError = GetLastError();
        printf("ERROR: StartIOSockets Failed to start socket     %d.\n",lastError);
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Listening on %d\n", ioPort);
    m_sockIO = accept(m_sockIOSrv, NULL, NULL);
    AfxBeginThread(&readThread, (LPVOID)NULL);
    AfxBeginThread(&writeThread, (LPVOID)NULL);
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: can't you use the MSG_DONTWAIT flag on recv so that it's non-blocking?

Comment: @dietbacon no, because it will make me busy wait constantly on the socket and cosume cpu for nothing.

Comment: Do you send data without requests?

Comment: Yes, the main purpuse of this code is to be a proxy between a remote user and a child process. The user sends the process' STDIN on the socket and recieves the STDOUT. I don't know when the user will send input so I read from the socket constatnly. I write to it only when the child process produces output, but then it gets stuck because the recv() is blocking. I could use two different sockets for that but the client code exists already and the linux code works fine, its only windows that is making problems. I wouldn't want to change too much the existing code, trying to handle it on windows.

Comment: The proper solution in Windows is to use asynchronous I/O, but that might make it difficult to share the code with the Linux implementation.  Perhaps select() would work?

Comment: We use select() in Linux for this logic, but unfortunately while Linux allows any fd to be used in select(), windows allows only sockets. In my case I read the input from a socket and the output from a pipe (and then write the input to another pipe and the output to the same socket, I hope that's not confusing) so I cannot use select(). I was afraid that my only option is AIO, wanted to check here first if there is any other solution to this problem. I would appriciate it if you could refer me to a good windows AIO tutorial if you know one. Thanks

Comment: On windows you could use `WSAWaitForMultipleEvents()` instead of `select()` and use an event object created with `WSACreateEvent()` instead of the pipe (if you are using the pipe just to wake up `select()`). Using two threads to read and write a socket is not the way to go.

Comment: Even if you are using a `select()`-like api call you should still switch the socket to non-blocking on each platform and should handle the `EWOULDBLOCK` error code on each socket handling api call (mainly `send()` and `recv()`). It may happen that your `select()`-like call signals but your actual `recv()` or `send()` still blocks if the socket isn't non-blocking. Treat `select()` and it's friends only as a very accurate (but not 100% accurate) predictor for socket readability/writability.